# Cannot update App.config file with WiX during installation

Tags: xml, wix

I would like to update the value of UserType in my app.config when I run the installer.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

App.config

```
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <Tool.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="UserType" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
        </Tool.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Tool.wxs

```
...
<util:XmlFile 
  Id="SetUserType"
  File="MyTool.exe.config"
  Action="setValue"
  Name="UserType"
  Value="1"
  ElementPath="//configuration/userSettings/Tool.Properties.Settings/setting"   />
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what XML you'd like to get at the end. Is it the `name` attribute of `<setting>` element that should change from `UserType` to something else? Or it is inner text of the `<value>` element, that should change from `0` to something?

Comment: I'd like to change the value from 0 to 1

Comment: Then `<XmlFile>` element should look a bit different - I'll shape it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the inner text of the value element, you should change the `<XmlFile>` declaration a bit:

```
<util:XmlFile Id="SetUserType"
              File="MyTool.exe.config"
              Action="setValue"
              Value="1"
              ElementPath="//configuration/userSettings/Tool.Properties.Settings/setting/value"   />
```

Couple of things to note here:

- the `ElementPath` attribute was corrected to point to the `<value>` element
- the `Name` attribute if omitted. In this case it sets the inner text of the element instead of setting a certain attribute value

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to not omit the Name?  I was planning to add a bunch of other settings like UserName, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your comment on Yan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054451/581187), you need to use ElementPath to select the setting with the correct name attribute.

```
<util:XmlFile Id="SetUserType" File="MyTool.exe.config" Action="setValue" Value="1"
ElementPath="/configuration/userSettings/Tool.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='UserType']/value"
/>
```

Change the `@name='UserType'` to whatever the other settings are named.